# LWC: Text Area Property Configuration

Tags: lightning-web-components

Looking through the [LWC Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_configuration_tags) there is a `type` for each property but the only options are Integer (text field), *String (text field)*, or Boolean (checkbox).

**Is there a way to create a Text Area field?**

I would think there is but I can't determine how based on the documentation. Also the placeholder spec mentions "text fields and text areas"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the three listed types are all that's available today. The "text area" bit refers to setting a placeholder for a textarea:

```
<textarea placeholder="Example Name"></textarea>
```